# Are dependency territory interchangeable in some situations?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

According to wiki (Crown dependencies),

> The Crown **dependencies** are three island **territories** off the coast of Great Britain that are self-governing possessions of the Crown: the Bailiwick of Guernsey, the Bailiwick of Jersey and the Isle of Man.

So, dependency is some kind of territory.

Another [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football) (The Football Association) says

> The Football Association (FA) is the governing body of association football in England and the Crown dependencies of Jersey, Guernsey, and the Isle of Man. Formed in 1863, it is the oldest football association in the world and is responsible for overseeing all aspects of the amateur and professional game in its **territory**.

Is it still idiomatic if I substitute **dependency** for **territory**?

How about another case?

> Jersey is a self-governing dependency of the United Kingdom.

substitute **dependency** for **territory**, we get

> Jersey is a self-governing territory of the United Kingdom.

Comment: No, because England is not a dependency, and also because the FA is not the Crown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *territory*  is just an area of land. *Crown dependencies* is a special term for the particular relationship which Jersey, Guernsey and the Isle of Man have with Great Britain (they are self-governing but, being small, *depend* on the UK for such things as defence). So, no, *dependency* is not just another word for *territory.*

Comment: Thank you. In this very specific situation. Is it appropriate to say "Jersey is a self-governing **territory** of the United Kingdom"?